Azure Data Factory: "Quote all text" inactive in Copy Data activity
I have an existing working pipeline in ADF. However, output CSV file in the storage container has every value enclosed in double quotes. I need to get rid of double quotes.
I presume, this happens because "Quote all text" option in the Sink tab is ticked in the Copy Data activity. I am unable to untick it as it seems inactive:

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

what is your source and sink

To remove all double quotes from the Data that is inserted into CSV you need to set the Quote character as No Quote character. Then it will not add quotes to the text.

Output for sample data:


Thank you @Pratik !
Connection details sit in the embedded data set, so was not straightforward to locate.
